# Error while using ternary operator in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to print an array with the following format:
1 .. double quote each element
2 .. put a comma between elements 
for some reason my code below doesn't generate the correct format

```
my @new_arr = (0 .. 5);
my $new_str = "";

for my $index ( 0 .. $#new_arr)
{
    print "$index .. $new_arr[$index]\n";
    ($index == $#new_arr) ?  $new_str.= "+\"$new_arr[$index]\"":$new_str.=     "\"$new_arr[$index]\"\,";

}
print "$new_str \n";
```

Comment: `$ perl -wE 'say join(",", map { qq{"$_"} } 0 .. 5)'`

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_str = q{"} . join( q{","}, @new_arr ) . q{"};
```

Example:

```
@new_arr = (0..5);
$new_str = q{"} . join( q{","}, @new_arr ) . q{"};
print $new_str,"\n";
```

Output:

```
"0","1","2","3","4","5"
```

---

`perl -MO=Deparse,-p ...` demonstrates the problem with your original code:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p ternary.pl
(@a = (0..5));
foreach my($index) (0 .. $#a) {
    print("$index .. $new_arr[$index]\n");
    ((($index == $#a) ? ($new_str .= qq[+"$a[$index]"]) : $new_str) .= qq["$a[$index]",]);
}
print("$new_str \n");
```

Namely, that the `.=` operators in the ternary expression are not grouped correctly. You could salvage it by using parentheses appropriately:

```
($index == $#new_arr) ? ($new_str.= "+\"$new_arr[$index]\""):($new_str.=     "\"$new_arr[$index]\"\,");
```

or pulling `$new_str .=` out of each side of the ternary expression

```
$new_str .= $index == $#new_arr ? "+\"$new_arr[$index]\"" : "\"$new_arr[$index]\"\,";
```

but ultimately this is a good use case for Perl's builtin `join` function.

Comment: Wouldn't `map` make this [cleaner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963507/error-while-using-ternary-operator-in-perl#comment65283784_38963507)?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -wE 'say join(",", map { qq{"$_"} } 0 .. 5)'
```

Output:

```
"0","1","2","3","4","5"
```

The initial [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) adds the double quotes, and then [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) creates a comma-separated string from the newly double-quoted list elements. We need to use [`qq`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) here because we want an interpolated string containing double quotes.